# Failed to set Database initializer Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm working through `Entity Framework` and `Web API` and I am running into this error below

```
"Failed to set database initializer of type 'Chorus.DAL.ChorusInitializer, Chorus' 
for DbContext type 'Chorus.DAL.ChorusContext, Chorus' specified in the application 
configuration. See inner exception for details."
```

(added) Here is the InnerException

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'Chorus' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

From what I gather it has to be in my web.config which is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Chorus.WebAPI-20150610073430.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Chorus.WebAPI-20150610073430;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ChorusContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=ChorusContext-20150720204839; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|ChorusContext-20150720204839.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings></appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="Chorus.DAL.ChorusContext, Chorus">
        <databaseInitializer type="Chorus.DAL.ChorusInitializer, Chorus" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I have looked through both my Context and Initializer and both are public and available.

Here is the Get Request creating the new context object

```
public class OrdersController : ApiController
    {

        private ChorusContext db = new ChorusContext();
        // GET: api/Orders
        [EnableQuery()]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {

            using (ChorusContext db = new ChorusContext())
            {
                var result = db.Orders.ToList();
                {
                    result = result.OrderBy(s => s.OrderId).ToList();
                }

                return this.Ok(result);
            }


        }
```

Here is the ChorusContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Chorus.WebAPI.DAL
{
    public class ChorusContext : DbContext
    {
        public ChorusContext() : base()
        {
            this.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
        }

        public DbSet<Chorus.WebAPI.Models.Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Chorus.WebAPI.Models.Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Chorus.WebAPI.Models.Warranty> Warrantys { get; set; }   
    }
```

and lastly here is the ChorusIntializer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace Chorus.WebAPI.DAL
{
    public class ChorusIntializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ChorusContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ChorusContext context)
        {
            var orders = new List<Chorus.WebAPI.Models.Order>
            {
                new Models.Order {data went here},

            };

            orders.ForEach(s => context.Orders.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `See inner exception for details`.  The answer lies here.  What does the InnerException have to say?

Comment: Sorry about that. Here it is {"Could not load file or assembly 'Chorus' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Chorus"}

Answer (score 0):

The namespace for both the Context and initializer in the code you've given is `Chorus.WebAPI.DAL`.

So make update this in your web.config:

```
<context type="Chorus.WebAPI.DAL.ChorusContext, Chorus">
    <databaseInitializer type="Chorus.WebAPI.DAL.ChorusInitializer, Chorus" />
</context>
```

You also need to make sure that the name of the assembly is correct in this config section - we can't see what that is from the information given, but it should be Chorus.dll. If its something else you'll need to set that too.